# Why does PHP use the characters "<?php"?

Tags: php, history

Of all the possible delimiters for server-side includes, why did PHP pick "less than question mark php"?

Rasmus (the inventer of PHP) replied to me privately, and since you closed the question, here is the answer:

It is an SGML Processing Instruction tag. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction.
It was originally `<? ... >` but the web moved to XML so it became `<? ... ?>`. I had left out the PITarget in the beginning since nobody else was using these in the web world but had to add it in when XML stuff started invading html.

Comment: boring day at office?

Comment: Yet surprisingly an interesting question. I'm curious now!

Comment: They figured you could use the exercise in typing `&lt;` for those 3 extra keystrokes perhaps?

Comment: @PRPGFerret too bad you wont get the answer now :P!

Answer (score 1):

Why not?... Take a look at short_opentag=On configuration if you want to write only '<?' But its not recommended and i'm not sure its already deprecated.

Comment: wow.... question was closed 8 minutes ago. this answer is posted 5 mintues ago. I wonder how it happened....

Comment: @itachi He's got `pull` ;-)